# How can i checkout a specific version of a branch in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branch, checkout

I need to checkout a branch from a specific check-in in TFS. Is there a specific option to do that? Performing "Get this version" after checking out the whole branch will do something?

Comment: Do you get any issue when perform "Get this version"? Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get This Version` or `Get Specific Version` effects your local workspace, it reverts all your local changes to an older version. So you can use it to check out old version.

[TFS Rollback vs "Get This Version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607513/tfs-rollback-vs-get-this-version)